# Android adb shell - Find and replace text within a file using command

Tags: android, shell, file-io, sed, adb

How to find and replace text within a file using adb command?

Is there any file edit command line in adb similar to **sed** command in linux and windows

sed does really good job with ease. However I could't find any similar way to do in Android

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

The above command replaces text with in a file However same doesn't work inside adb shell

```
C:\Users\^^^^\Desktop>adb shell sed
/system/bin/sh: sed: not found
```

My device is not rooted and no plans to **root** my device

Comment: For what it's worth, the Android devices I've seen recently do have `sed` on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root, you can [install busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.busybox.installer) on the device and use sed that way:

`adb shell busybox sed`

Otherwise, you're limited to what the Android OS ships with, which is almost nothing useful.

Comment: I dint mention in my question. However i am wondering if any solution with out rooting device